# Complex 301 .htaccess url redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have tried several simple ways like

```
Redirect 301 ^/gebouw/start/(.*) http://mysub.domain.nl/start/$1
```

and some more elaborate

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/gebouw/start/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysub.domain.nl/start/$1 [R,L]
```

but I do not get the succes I want

What I'm looking for is to 301 redirect every page that is browsed to from www.myolddomain.nl/start/ to mysub.domain.nl/start/
these url's can get complex, they range from

http://www.myolddomain.nl/start/resetpassword.php

to

http://www.myolddomain.nl/start/subdir/page.php?var1=inputBlad&var2=6378

how can I do this best with htaccess rules?

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm looking for is to 301 redirect every page that is browsed to from www.myolddomain.nl/start/ to mysub.domain.nl/start/ these url's can get complex, they range from

You want to be doing this then:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myolddomain.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?start/(.*)$ http://mysub.domain.nl/start/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This doesn't specify the start folder. I only want to add the redirect to paths with the start folder in it.

Comment: @DaniëlTulp then add the `/start/` to the match and target (see edit)

Comment: I wasn't able to sort this out, possibly because my host gets in the way. I ended up using php to do the redirection (a lot easier to test also), sorry I can't mark your answer as correct as I do not know it to be so.